# How can I unify text that take from multiple group radio button and multiple group checkbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox, radio-button

My javascript code like this :

```
$(function(){
    $('input[type="radio"]').click(function(){
        var $radio = $(this);
        var name = $(this).prop("name");

        // if this was previously checked
        if ($radio.data('waschecked') == true)
        {
            $radio.prop('checked', false);
            $radio.data('waschecked', false);
            $('#result-select').text('');
        }
        else{
            $radio.data('waschecked', true);
            $("input[name=\""+name+"\"]:not(:checked)").data('waschecked', false);
            $('#result-select').text(txt);
        }

        var output = [];
        var txt;
        $('input[type="radio"]:checked').each( function() {
                txt = $(this).parent().text();
                output.push(txt);
        });
        $('#result-select').text(output.join(' - '));
    });
});
```

Demo and full code like this : https://jsfiddle.net/oscar11/m7by6zcw/41/

I want to :

If I select chelsea, madrid and juve the result like this :

> Chelsea - Madrid - Juve

If I select chelsea and madrid the result like this :

> Chelsea - Madrid

If I select chelsea, madrid, juve and milan the result like this :

> Chelsea - Madrid - Juve - Milan

So if I check radio button, it display the text. If I uncheck radio button, it not display the text. I check combobox, it display the text. If I uncheck combobox, it not display the text

For example the text :

> Chelsea - Madrid - Juve - Milan

I uncheck Juve, the result like this :

> Chelsea - Madrid - Milan

On the radio button, it works
But on the checkbox, I'm still confused

How can I do it?

**Update** :

The radio button can be unchecked

For example :

If I select chelsea, madrid and juve the result like this :

> Chelsea - Madrid - Juve

Then I uncheck madrid, the result like this :

> Chelsea - Juve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify the input element selector to handle both input types checkboxes and radio buttons:

```
$('.list-unstyled input').....
```

**[Working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/4e9npyn6/)**

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```js
var $radioAndCheckboxInputs = $('input:radio, input:checkbox');
var $resultSelect = $('#result-select');
$radioAndCheckboxInputs.click(function () {
  var output = [];
  $radioAndCheckboxInputs.filter(':checked').each(function () {
    output.push($(this).parent().text());
  });
  $resultSelect.text(output.join(' - '));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-4">
    <ul class="list-unstyled">
        <li><strong>England</strong></li>
        <li>
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="england" class="radio"> Chelsea
                </label>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="england" class="radio"> Mu
                </label>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="england" class="radio"> Arsenal
                </label>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
    <ul class="list-unstyled">
        <li><strong>Spain</strong></li>
        <li>
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="spain" class="radio"> Madrid
                </label>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="spain" class="radio"> Barcelona
                </label>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="spain" class="radio"> Atletico
                </label>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="col-md-4">
    <ul class="list-unstyled">
        <li><strong>Italy</strong></li>
        <li>
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="italy" class="radio"> Juve
                </label>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="italy" class="radio"> Milan
                </label>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="italy" class="radio"> Inter
                </label>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<span id="result-select">Result</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the working code:**

```js
 var output = [];
 var txt;
 $(function(){
 
    $('input[type="radio"]').click(function(){
       mainLogic();
    });
     $('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function(){
       mainLogic();
     });

});

function mainLogic(){
        output = [];
        txt='';
        $('input[type="radio"]:checked').each( function() {
          txt = $(this).parent().text();
          output.push(txt);
        });
         $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each( function() {
          txt = $(this).parent().text();
          output.push(txt);
        });
        $('#result-select').text(output.join(' - '));

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-4">
    <ul class="list-unstyled">
        <li><strong>England</strong></li>
        <li>
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="england" class="radio"> Chelsea
                </label>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="england" class="radio"> Mu
                </label>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="england" class="radio"> Arsenal
                </label>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
    <ul class="list-unstyled">
        <li><strong>Spain</strong></li>
        <li>
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="spain" class="radio"> Madrid
                </label>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="spain" class="radio"> Barcelona
                </label>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="spain" class="radio"> Atletico
                </label>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="col-md-4">
    <ul class="list-unstyled">
        <li><strong>Italy</strong></li>
        <li>
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="italy" class="radio"> Juve
                </label>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="italy" class="radio"> Milan
                </label>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="italy" class="radio"> Inter
                </label>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<span id="result-select">Result</span>
```